# php regular expression. Alphabet with spaces only after the first word

Tags: php, regex

What is a php regular expression that will allow letters and spaces. But spaces only after the first word?

Thank You

Comment: "Spaces only after the first word" or "Spaces between words"?

Comment: why not just allow spaces at the front, and then `trim()` it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$rex = '/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*$/';
```

Or

```
$rex = '/^[a-z][a-z ]*$/i'; // i means case insensitive
```